# System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll in c# consol application

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I am new in entityframework and I start with this code, but I do not know why I got an exception handler "System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll" in line  var count = context.Albums.Count();

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Data.Entity;

    namespace entityframework1
      {
        class Program
         {
           static void Main(string[] args)
            {
              using (var context = new MusicAlbumContext())
                 {
                      var count = context.Albums.Count();
                      Console.WriteLine(count);
                      context.Albums.Add(new Album() { Name = "best", Cost = 34.43m });
                     context.SaveChanges();
                     Console.WriteLine(count);
                     Console.Read();
        }
    }
}



      public  class MusicAlbumContext:DbContext
        {
          public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
        }

     public   class Album
       {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Cost { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: There should be a lot more information in the exception, what does it say?

Comment: I bet it has to do with your model not having an id. Add     [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int id { get; set; }

Comment: @knuturO yes that is true; Thank you very much; I should define an Id field in Album class

Comment: @KnuturO EF should do this automatically (well at least is does in v6, and I assume v4)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following process

```
class Program
     {
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          using (var context = new MusicAlbumContext())
             {
                  var count = context.Albums.Count();
                  Console.WriteLine(count);
                  context.Albums.Add(new Album() { Name = "best", Cost = 34.43m });
                 context.SaveChanges();
                 Console.WriteLine(count);
                 Console.Read();
    }
}
```

}

```
  public  class MusicAlbumContext:DbContext
    {
      public MusicAlbumContext()
        : base("connectionstring")
    {

    }
    static MusicAlbumContext()
{
    Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MusicAlbumContext>());
}
      public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
    }

 public   class Album
   {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
```

}

after that run the following commnads
enable-migrations contextname
add-migration InitialCreate
update-database -verbose -fource

Comment: Why do you think this would have any effect at all?